# Где хранятся переменые среды в Linux?

Tags: linux, переменные-среды

Где хранятся переменные среды в `Linux`, если точнее, в `Kali Linux`?

Более конкретный вопрос, как мне удалить переменную `_JAVA_OPTIONS`, которая выскакивает всякий раз, когда я использую программы, связанные с явой, с этой своей строчкой
`Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true`?
Я могу, конечно, написать `unset _JAVA_OPTIONS` в файле `.bashrc`, но это решение костыльное, и оно мне не нравится.

Comment: На хабре была статья какой путь проходит система с момента запуска до момента логина пользователя, и на каждом этапе появляются переменные окружения. Но сейчас не смог найти. Может вам повезет :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если кратко - везде. Но есть основные места. Глобальные хранятся в папке /etc. Я обычно в этом случае делаю `grep _JAVA_OPTIONS /etc -r` и смотрю.

Второе - это в домашнем каталоге в .bashrc, .bash_profile или других файлах, если используется не баш. Но стратегия поиска та же.

Но править ручками каталог /env может быть опасно (можно и систему сломать). Именно для этого и придумали локальный профиль.

Поэтому

> Я могу, конечно, написать unset _JAVA_OPTIONS в файле .bashrc, но это решение костыльное, и оно мне не нравится.

как по мне, отличное решение.

Comment: Папку /env я найти не смог, а при запуске `grep _JAVA_OPTIONS /etc` программа пишет `grep: /etc: Это каталог`.

Comment: `grep -r _JAVA_OPTIONS /etc`... и видимо он имел в виду каталог `/etc/env.d`...

Comment: да, очепятка...

Comment: @Fat-Zer такого каталога нет, но в `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90kali-themes` и `/etc/environment.d/95kali-themes.conf` нашёл.

Comment: Не понимаю, почему это может быть опасно. Удалю всего одну строчку со всего одной переменной.

Comment: если Вы изменяете системные файлы, то другие приложения вдруг могут перестать работать (они могли рассчитывать на именно такое состояние этих переменных окружения). Плюс, пакетный менеджер скорее всего перетрет при следующем обновлении (или откажется).

Comment: @ИмяФамилия, нуда... в пост-systemd системах оному соответствует `/etc/environment.d`...

Answer (score 1):

> Я могу, конечно, написать unset _JAVA_OPTIONS в файле .bashrc, но это решение костыльное, и оно мне не нравится.

Есть другие способы удаления переменной окружения, выбирайте на свой вкус.

Для примера создадим скрипт `test.sh` (и еще `chmod +x test.sh`) который будет выводить все переменные окружения:

```
#!/bin/bash

env
```

Теперь попробуем удалить переменную `PAGER`, в вашем случая она будет `_JAVA_OPTIONS`.

```
./test.sh | grep PAGER                                                                                              1 ↵
PAGER=less
```

Переменная есть

### Удаление одной переменной

```
env -uPAGER ./test.sh | grep PAGER
(пусто)
```

### Полное удаление переменных

```
env -i ./test.sh | grep PAGER
(пусто)
```

Переменной нет. А также и других переменных окружения

### Пустое значение

```
PAGER= ./test.sh | grep PAGER
PAGER=
```

Переменная пустая

Comment: Таким образом я могу удалить переменную для одной отдельной команды, а я хочу удалить её навсегда.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия тогда `unset _JAVA_OPTIONS в файле .bashrc` или отгрепайте все файлы, начиная с /etc в поисках _JAVA_OPTIONS и удалите оттуда.

Comment: Мне тут сказали, что редактирование системных файлов к хорошему не приводит, так что я решил всё-таки отредактировать `.bashrc`.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия, если не умело что-то делать и не отдавать себе в этом отчет, то можно. Но это также поправимо в большинстве случаев. На счет java не могу сказать, но во многих пакетах (apache2, php - точно), если править конфиги в /etc то при обновлении пакета установщик говорит "такие файлы изменились, что будем делать? посмотреть отличия, использовать файл из репы или оставить существующий файл, или отредактировать?". Таким образом, внесенные в конфиги изменения можно сохранить и после обновления. Я думаю удаление _JAVA_OPTIONS из файла конфига не повредит ничему.